# How to get the day number in fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I´m using the fullcalendar.io and I want to display the day number(eg 1 for monday) when I click on a cell in the monad column to add an event.

I have tried with alert(event.day); etc but no luck.
Any suggestions appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/

> From the docs:
>
> function( date, jsEvent, view, [ resourceObj ] ) { }
>
> date holds a Moment for the clicked day.

```
function dayClick(date, jsEvent, view) {
    console.log(date.day()); //day of the week: 1 for monday
    console.log(date.get('date')); //day of month: 20 for today
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found it in the end :-)

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson glad to know it helped. You can mark it as resolved then.